# Doxygen / source file comments

Tags: doxygen

Is any way to not generates warrnings from undocumented function/method that is located in  source file ( .c ) . I have all comments in header file and do not want to duplicate it.
I do not want to switch off documenting source code but only comments for method in this file.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches you could take, both by changing config options in your Doxyfile:

1. If you set [WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_warn_if_undocumented) to False (it defaults to True), doxygen won't complain about any function or method which is undocumented.  (You might not want to do that though, as the warnings can be a helpful way to check you've documented all your methods and functions.)
2. Set your config to include or exclude files based on their suffix.  For example: if the methods and functions which are causing problems all have a .c suffix, you can set [EXCLUDE_PATTERNS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_patterns) to `*.c` to ignore all .c files.

The doxygen [configuration documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) is pretty comprehensive, and you may find another approach in there which suits better.

Comment: I was considering this solution but  . in c file I have comments about authors,group ( module ) etc.

Comment: So maybe WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = False would be the way to go?  You could also look at suppressing warnings wholesale using [WARNINGS = NO](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_warnings), though it is something of a large hammer...